# Why some pages use server-side redirect instead of direct linking for external webs?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I've seen that some pages have links that instead of pointing to the final web page, it points to an internal URL that redirects you to the final web page.

For example, [this page of hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-pointer) is a challenge about pointers. At the very beginning, it has a link to the [Wikipedia article about pointers in CS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)).

I would have expected the following in the `<a>` tag.

```
<p>A <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)" target="_blank">pointer</a> in C...</p>
```

However, this is what I found.

```
<p>A <a href="https://www.hackerrank.com/external_redirect?to=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29" target="_blank">pointer</a> in C...</p>
```

I don't understand why someone would add `https://www.hackerrank.com/external_redirect?to=` to every external link.

Does it have an effect on the number of links to the external URL, Wikipedia in this case? Does it improve SEO? What difference does it make to Hackerrank to define links this way?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe they use it for analytics to tell which links people are clicking that causes them to leave their site?

Comment: Well, that would actually explain it. But isn't there an easier way to analyse how many clicks get a link without messing with the server? I've seen some webs that write a number just after the link indicating the number of clicks it has. An example would be FreeCodeCamp Forums https://forum.freecodecamp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in any of this, but my guess would be it's used for analytics to tell which links people are clicking that are causing them to leave the website.

The example you gave with the FCC Forums increasing their view count is not the same thing. Those are links to internal pages. If they wanted to increase a topic's view count they would probably just do so when the topic is actually loaded, not when a user clicks on a hyperlink to take them there.

You can't do that when you link someone to an external page because your browser doesn't notify the server that you're leaving the website, it just goes to the link.